# Is new int[][] a valid thing to do in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have come across some code which allocates a 2d array with following approach:

```
auto a = new int[10][10];
```

Is this a valid thing to do in C++? I have search through several C++ reference books, none of them has mentioned such approach. 
Normally I would have done the allocation manually as follow:

```
int  **a = new int *[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[10];
}
```

If the first approach is valid, then which one is preferred?

Comment: It's preferred not to use `new` at all.

Comment: if size known in advance and it is not great better not use new.

Comment: To be fair, there are cases where you still need to use `new` for this kind of thing (e.g. calling legacy APIs), so it would be better to answer the question as posed, rather than dispensing grandfatherly advice on modern C++ best practices. ;-)

Comment: "Is this a valid thing to do in C++?" – what makes you think it isn't? Seems a pretty basic language feature, if it compiles it's probably perfectly valid.

Comment: The post and answers would have been clearer had the 2 dimensions been different values like `int[10][20]`.

Comment: @ Paul R Even when using legacy API, the C++11 `std::vector::data()` member (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) gives you access to the underlying pointer, if needed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first example:

```
auto a = new int[10][10];
```

That allocates a *multidimensional array* or *array of arrays* as a contiguous block of memory.

The second example:

```
int** a = new int*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[10];
}
```

That is not a true *multidimensional array*. It is, in fact, an *array of pointers* and requires two indirections to access each element.

Comment: Good answer, apart from "This makes it faster to access than the second example" - I don't think you can really say this with any certainty.

Comment: The first is an array of arrays, the second is an array of pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this was possible. Good to know.

Comment: @PaulR I changed the wording, would you say that is accurate? It is my understanding that being a contiguous block gives it the potential advantage of accessing the elements using one indirection and the rest is subscripted using a multiplication.

Comment: @Galik: well it's a trade-off between memory accesses and address arithmetic, so it will be very CPU-dependent and may even vary according to access pattern, so I would just omit any discussion of performance, since there is nothing generally applicable in this case, and in practise there is likely be little difference between the two.

Comment: Allocating a two-dimensional array guarantees that the entire array is in a single contiguous block of memory. With an array of pointers, on the other hand, each segment could be anywhere in memory, which may greatly increase the probability of cache misses.

Comment: @Ferrucio: true, but only for a naïve implementation of an array of pointers. Any programmer worth their salt will allocate a single block for the data and then initialise row pointers into this single block.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `new int[10][10]` means to allocate an array of ten elements of type `int[10]`, so yes, it is a valid thing to do.

The type of the pointer returned by new is `int(*)[10]`; one could declare a variable of such a type via `int (*ptr)[10];`.

For the sake of legibility, one probably shouldn't use that syntax, and should prefer to use `auto` as in your example, or use a typedef to simplify as in

```
using int10 = int[10]; // typedef int int10[10];
int10 *ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, for small arrays, it is more efficient to allocate them on the stack. Perhaps even using a convenience wrapper such as `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>`. However, in general, it is valid to do something like the following:

```
auto arr = new int[a][b];
```

Where `a` is a `std::size_t` and `b` is a `constexpr std::size_t`. This results in more efficient allocation as there should only be one call to `operator new[]` with `sizeof(int) * a * b` as the argument, instead of the `a` calls to `operator new[]` with `sizeof(int) * b` as the argument. As stated by Galik in his answer, there is also the potential for faster access times, due to increased cache coherency (the entire array is contiguous in memory).

However, the only reason I can imagine one using something like this would be with a compile-time-sized matrix/tensor, where all of the dimensions are known at compile time, but it allocates on the heap if it exceeds the stack size.

In general, it is probably best to write your own RAII wrapper class like follows (you would also need to add various accessors for height/width, along with implementing a copy/move constructor and assignment, but the general idea is here:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
     Matrix( std::size_t height, std::size_t width ) : m_height( height ), m_width( width )
     {
           m_data = new T[height * width]();
     }

     ~Matrix() { delete m_data; m_data = nullptr; }

public:
     T&               operator()( std::size_t x, std::size_t y )
     {
          // Add bounds-checking here depending on your use-case
          // by throwing a std::out_of_range if x/y are outside 
          // of the valid domain.
          return m_data[x + y * m_width];
     }

     const T&         operator()( std::size_t x, std::size_t y ) const
     {
          return m_data[x + y * m_width];
     }

private:
     std::size_t      m_height;
     std::size_t      m_width;
     T*               m_data;
};
```